# Expand Excel Spreadsheet out based on a column

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet like this:

```
Name        Online         Retail         Trade
Widget 1    $352           $532           $235
```

I need to get it looking like this

```
Price Level       Price      Name
Online            $352       Widget 1
Retail            $532       Widget 1
Trade             $235       Widget 1
```

Is that possible with Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For how to flatten your data please [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-flatten/20543651#20543651) and then re-order and rename your columns to suit.